# Testing with Mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to test my app using Mocha. Like so:

```
it('should throw error if FILE already exists', function () {
    const path = 'test/styles/header/style.css'
    createNew(path).catch(err => {
        return assert.equal(err, 'already exists')
    })
})
```

and `createNew`:

```
const createNew = function(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (fs.existsSync(providedPath)) {
           reject('already exists')
           return
        }
...
```

Is it good practice to test promises the way i am doing it?

Comment: Seems fine to me. On a side note, if you want to use `this` inside mocha test you don't want to use arrow function but classic function (explanation : https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2016/08/20/arrow-functions-in-mocha/)